# Spring Data Aggregate Query

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Team,

I am new to Spring data for mongodb. I am trying to learn the Spring data code for aggregation query. but most of the tutorial shown only the simple examples. Could you **please** help me build the spring data code for the given complex aggregate example.

```
SCHEMA:
{
    "s"  : "CB",
    "c"  : "REQ_RCV",
    "e"  : "cta_sms_click",
    "st" : "i",
    "b"  : "UB",
    "a"  : "account-1",
    "u"  : "b1_h1_d1_m1_user_2",
    "c#" : "b1_h1_d1_m1_cr-2",
    "@"  : ISODate("2016-10-01T06:03:00.000Z"),
    "@h" : "16100106",
    "@d" : "161001",
    "@m" : "1610"
}


QUERY:
db.COLLECTION_NAME.aggregate([                       
        {$match:{"st":"i","@":{$gte : new ISODate("2015-10-01T06:00:00Z"), $lte : new ISODate("2017-10-02T10:00:00Z")}, "c":"REQ_RCV"}}, 
        {$group:{_id:{"b":"$b", "HOURLY":"$@h"}, count:{$sum:1}}}, 
        {$project : {_id:0, "BUCKET":"$_id.b", "TIME":"$_id.HOURLY", count:1}},
        {$sort:{"BUCKET":1, "TIME":1}}                     
    ]);
```

Complexities:

1. $match has muliple criterias
2. $project has to access the inner field of group under _id
3. The result can not be mapped to a class since it varies based on $project field changes. Ultimately i would
   like to map it to java.util.HashMap, so that i can put any fields
   inside $project. Is that possible?

---

Initial answer from Veeram for reference:

---

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(match(where("st").is("i").and("@").gte(start_date).lte(end_date).and("c").is("REQ_RCV")),
                    group(fields("b").and("HOURLY", "$@h")).count().as("count"),
                    project(fields("count").and("BUCKET","$_id.b").and("TIME", "$_id.HOURLY")),
                    sort(ASC, "BUCKET", "TIME"));
```

Comment: @chridam Could you please help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like below. Replace with your date values and collection name.

```
import static org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction.ASC;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.where;

Aggregation agg = newAggregation(match(where("st").is("i").and("@").gte(new Date()).lte(new Date()).and("c").is("REQ_RCV")),
            group(fields("b").and("HOURLY", "$@h")).count().as("count"),
            sort(ASC, Aggregation.previousOperation()));

List<BasicDBObject> dbObjects = mongoOperations.aggregate(agg, "collection_name", BasicDBObject.class).getMappedResults();
```

Comment: One query. Declaring name at `project` like "BUCKET" and "TIME" is mandatory to call it in `sort`? And is that not possible to write `sort(ASC, "$_id.b", "$_id.HOURLY")` ?

Comment: Updated the answer. Sorry, I should have spotted that. You can use `previousOperation()` for sorting which holds the reference to the previously group `_id`

Comment: Thanks! But i will keep your both answers :)

Answer (score 2):

So there is probably a more spring-data way of doing this but what im doing is wiring the MongoTemplate and using that to the Aggreagation query. My Example us much simpler than what you want to do but maybe it can help :

```
    @Service
     public class AClass implements CategoryStructureService {

            @Autowired
            private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate ;

    ......
    private int method(CategoryStructureKey csKey) {

            Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.match(Criteria
                    .where("_id").is(csKey)), Aggregation.unwind("fields"),
                    Aggregation.project("fields").andExclude("_id"), Aggregation
                            .sort(Direction.DESC, "fields.index"), Aggregation
                            .limit(1));

AggregationResults<MultiValuedFieldContainer> field = mongoTemplate
                .aggregate(agg, CategoryStructure.class,
                        MultiValuedFieldContainer.class);
        ....

        }
```

I did this with an old spring-boot project, having this as a dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

So it should work.

You can find a better example of MongoTemplate here 
https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-aggregation-grouping-example/

And some other Agrregation examples 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/AggregationTests.java

Hope this helps